# "Relative to", "compared to", or "than" which is best to describe a positional relationship?

Tags: relative-adverbs

On most planes, business class seats are located on the front side (relative to, compared to, than) economy class seats.  Which expression is best for this sentence.  Could you please advise if there is any more suitable expressions.

Comment: Instead of this, you can make the sentence clearer by stating the location of the economy seats: On most planes, business class seats are located at the front, whereas economy class seats are located at the back.

Comment: I want to use comparative expressions.

Comment: If so, then _relative_ _to_ is the only correct one.

Comment: You may also consider, "as opposed to,
And as Rose had said, it's "at the" front, not "on the" front.

Comment: The phrase *on the front side" is unusual. Normally we refer to "front", "rear" or "back" and "sides". The word "backside" sometimes means the "back" or the "rear" of something, it more commonly means the "rump" or "buttocks". The words "frontside" and "backside" are also used in sports like surfing and snowboarding for aspects of turning.

Comment: I wonder whether native speakers use the expression  "located at the front relative to" because only five results were found  when I searched for this expression on google.

Comment: Another way to express this using a comparative expression would be *business class seats are located **closer to the front (of the plane) than** economy class seats*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add "relative to" because that idea is already expressed implicitly in the words "front", "rear", "left", and "right".

I think what you're trying to get at is **further forward** or **further to the rear**.

> We are in business class. First class begins further forward.
>
> Sir, coach seating is located further to the rear (of the plane). I'm going to have to ask you to move.
>
> Could you please move the painting a little farther to the left?

Comment: +1 OP might want to note that in American English, some folks hold to the distinction that *f**a**rther* should be used for physical distance, and *f**u**rther* reserved for metaphorical use (I don't personally care, but just in case you run into a persnickety teacher or editor).

Comment: Both **further** and **farther** can be used in AmE when referring to  degree or extent.  I'm fairly persnickety.

Comment: I agree they can, and often are; but if you google "further vs farther" you'll see that some folks make a distinction. It's one of those prescriptive rules that ought to go away, but for learners I think it makes sense to point them out along with the common-sense instruction that it's not a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=farther+to+the+left%2Cfurther+to+the+left%2Cfarther+to+the+right%2Cfurther+to+the+right&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfarther%20to%20the%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfurther%20to%20the%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfarther%20to%20the%20right%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfurther%20to%20the%20right%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=further+forward%2Cfarther+forward&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfurther%20forward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfarther%20forward%3B%2Cc0

Comment: “"Further" Versus "Farther" The quick and dirty tip is to use “farther” for physical distance and “further” for metaphorical, or figurative, distance. It's easy to remember because “farther” has the word “far” in it, and “far” obviously relates to physical distance.” — [Grammar Girl : "Further" Versus "Farther" :: Quick and Dirty Tips](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/further-versus-farther&ved=0ahUKEwjf1ZGWzfTRAhXM24MKHaYSDwkQFggnMAI&usg=AFQjCNEh-SO6vnISWlaiRWjRjk9OtOhw8w). This is a boxed Google results answer, too.

Comment: To be clear, I don't mean that your usage is in any way wrong. Just that it is possible that the OP might run into people who claim that it is, just as it is possible to run into people who object to ever splitting infinitives (another bit of errant nonsense up with which I must occasionally put).